# Named entities in Reportlab

Tags: python, html-entities, reportlab, mathml

I just learned that Reportlab will support named entities like `&alpha;` and `&approx;` in paragraph text. Exactly which entities will it support?

Here's an example of how it works:

```
from reportlab.lib.styles import getSampleStyleSheet
from reportlab.platypus import SimpleDocTemplate, Paragraph


def main():
    styles = getSampleStyleSheet()
    pdf_path = 'sketch.pdf'
    doc = SimpleDocTemplate(pdf_path)

    story = [Paragraph('Lorem ipsum! &alpha; &approx; 90&deg;', styles['Normal']),
             Paragraph('Dolores sit amet.', styles['Normal'])]

    doc.build(story)


main()
```

Answer (score 0):

Tracing through the Reportlab source code, I found that it supports everything from Python's [`html.entities` module](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.10/Lib/html/entities.py), plus its [own list](https://hg.reportlab.com/hg-public/reportlab/file/697141ce83e1/src/reportlab/platypus/paraparser.py#l364) of over 2000 entries, although there seems to be a lot of overlap.